# HTML5 video not playing in android webview

Tags: android, flutter, webview, html5-video

Having trouble getting HTML5 basic example to work in Flutter webview on android.

Created a basic flutter app (Channel beta, 1.26.0-17.8.pre) with a webview and running in android emulator, loading a HTML file from assets folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello World!

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="./video/small.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

with main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(TestApp());
}

class TestApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HelpScreenState createState() {
    return HelpScreenState();
  }
}

class TestAppState extends State<TestApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter WebView',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: TA());
  }
}

class TA extends StatelessWidget {
  WebViewController _controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Test')),
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: 'about:blank',
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _controller = webViewController;
          _loadHtmlFromAssets();
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _loadHtmlFromAssets() async {
    String fileText = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/test.html');
    _controller.loadUrl( Uri.dataFromString(
        fileText,
        mimeType: 'text/html',
        encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8')
    ).toString());
  }
}
```

And pubspec.yaml

```
name: webviewtest
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  webview_flutter: ^1.0.7
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  
  assets:
    - assets/test.html
```

Result is video element loading but the video itself does not load in the player. I have run this HTML file natively in the browser and it loads the source video fine.

Run output:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53746/JOjSncP67JU=/ws
Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86 arm...
I/WebViewFactory(31624): Loading com.google.android.webview version 83.0.4103.106 (code 410410681)
I/ple.webviewtes(31624): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
D/nativeloader(31624): classloader namespace configured for unbundled product apk. library_path=/product/app/WebViewGoogle/lib/x86:/product/app/WebViewGoogle/WebViewGoogle.apk!/lib/x86:/product/app/TrichromeLibrary/TrichromeLibrary.apk!/lib/x86:/product/lib:/system/product/lib
W/Gralloc4(31624): allocator 3.x is not supported
I/ple.webviewtes(31624): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
D/nativeloader(31624): classloader namespace configured for unbundled product apk. library_path=/product/app/WebViewGoogle/lib/x86:/product/app/WebViewGoogle/WebViewGoogle.apk!/lib/x86:/product/app/TrichromeLibrary/TrichromeLibrary.apk!/lib/x86:/product/lib:/system/product/lib
I/cr_LibraryLoader(31624): Loaded native library version number "83.0.4103.106"
I/cr_CachingUmaRecorder(31624): Flushed 3 samples from 3 histograms.
I/TetheringManager(31624): registerTetheringEventCallback:com.example.webviewtest
W/chromium(31624): [WARNING:dns_config_service_posix.cc(341)] Failed to read DnsConfig.
D/HostConnection(31624): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf7085d40, tid 31716
W/ple.webviewtes(31624): Accessing hidden method Landroid/media/AudioManager;->getOutputLatency(I)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/HostConnection(31624): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
E/chromium(31624): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(549)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS
D/EGL_emulation(31624): eglCreateContext: 0xf7083dc0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation(31624): eglMakeCurrent: 0xf7083dc0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc4127230) (first time)
E/chromium(31624): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(549)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS
I/VideoCapabilities(31624): Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
W/cr_MediaCodecUtil(31624): HW encoder for video/avc is not available on this device.
D/EGL_emulation(31624): eglCreateContext: 0xf7085e20: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
```

NOTE: I created a new project and used a standard HTML boilerplate with the same main.dart file as above

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello Flutter!
</body>
</html>
```

And the output from the run command oddly contains:

```
I/VideoCapabilities(31299): Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
W/cr_MediaCodecUtil(31299): HW encoder for video/avc is not available on this device.
```

Any idea why this isn't working and how i can get it to work?

EDIT: As suggested, tried using mp4 source file and adding reference to the assets section of pubspec.yml.

pubspec.yml assets section after edit:

```
  assets:
    - assets/test.html
    - assets/video/mov_bbb.mp4
```

test.html after edit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello World!
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="./video/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Change had no identifiable effect to output or to display of the video.

This is what i am seeing:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see here: https://caniuse.com/?search=ogv, the `.ogv` format is not supported on Android WebView.
You can use other video formats, such as `.mp4`!

Also, I think you should probably declare the asset video file in the `pubspec.yml`:

```yaml
...

assets:
  - assets/test.html
  - assets/video/mov_bbb.mp4 # or simply assets/video/
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I started with MP4 though, and only moved to Ogg when i didn't have any luck. I'll try again and declare the asset and see if that is indeed the answer, and report back.

Comment: I have tried it with no success as expected. Please see additional detail in OP

Comment: It's strange! However, I tried with the [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview) plugin and it worked! Maybe you could try it

Comment: I tried to do it using flutter_inappwebview but getting the same result. Any way you can share your code using flutlab.io or similar? I am probably making a silly mistake.

Comment: Yeah sure! I will add a new comment here as soon as possible

Comment: @mysticfakir I was unable to use flutlab.io because it doesn't allow me to upload the .mp4 video example there. So, I have updated my answer here with the code example and with the link of the .mp4 video file I used.

Comment: Success! Thanks for your help. Once i had code that was confirmed working, i was able to debug that it was the emulator that was the issue.